# How to install INTEL GRAPHICS INSTALLER from source code

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

My OS is ubuntu 14.04, I want to install INTEL GRAPHICS INSTALLER on my system. However, the binary file of latest version (1.4.0) of INTEL GRAPHICS INSTALLER doesn't support ubuntu 14.04 (it supports 15.10).

It seems that the only way to install it is compiling from source. But I don't know compile and install it.

Comment: Did you try downloading and installing it from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.0).

Comment: @VishnuNK The binary installer they provided seems only support Ubuntu 15.10.